# Converting a string array of numbers to a double array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, double

I have a string array of all numbers and i need to convert it to double so i can do stuff with it later on, I need to do something like this.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] String = File.ReadAllLines("../Program/Files/Numbers.txt");
        double[] Double = String;
    }
```

I've tried using a for loop to convert it line by line but everything i've tried gives me an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

I'm pretty new to c# coding and I don't know any other ways to do it. 
I think it should be simple and I hope I don't seem too stupid not being able to figure it out.

Really appreciate any help anyone can give :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through a loop to assign each entry individually. Assuming each line of the file is it's own data entry, this should not be very hard to do. Otherwise, you can search for the String.Split() method to learn how to break it up. An example might look something like this:

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("../Program/Files/Numbers.txt");
double[] fileDouble = new double[fileLines.Length];
for(int i=0; i < fileLines.Length ; i++){
    Double.TryParse(fileLines[i], out fileDouble[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using Linq..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] StringNumbers = File.ReadAllLines("../Program/Files/Numbers.txt");
        double[] Double = StringNumbers.ToList().ConvertAll(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToArray();
    }
```

`Convert.ToDouble` : Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent double-precision floating-point number. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `double.Parse()`

```
var myDouble = double.Parse("27.89");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

All the built-in numeric types hava a parse function to convert from strings